# Declaration of method changes meaning of symbol

Tags: c++, token-name-resolution

For the following code:

```
struct foo {};

struct A
{
    typedef foo foo_type;

    void foo();
};
```

GCC gives a compiler error:

```
test.cpp:7:14: error: declaration of 'void A::foo()' [-fpermissive]
     void foo();
              ^
test.cpp:1:8: error: changes meaning of 'foo' from 'struct foo' [-fpermissive]
 struct foo {};
        ^
```

But clang accepts it without compiler errors. Who is right?

Note that if the typedef is removed, or changed to `typedef ::foo foo_type`, both gcc and clang accept the code.

Comment: The real question is: *Why* is Clang always right?

Comment: when there's no typedef then it is not strange

Comment: @cf16: I didn't say it was. I just wanted to point out that, in spite of the error not mentioning the typedef, the typedef has something to do with the error.

Comment: Try it with `typedef ::foo foo_type;` instead.

Comment: @user315052: That also makes the error go away. My question still stands though.

Comment: You can also "solve" it with `typedef struct foo foo_type;`. And the behaviour changes if you swap the `typedef` and the function declaration.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

gcc is correct, but clang is not required to give a diagnostic (3.3.7):

> A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in its
>   context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S. No
>   diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

This is because of how class scope works. The `foo` of `void foo();` is visible within the **entire** scope of the class `A`, so the declaration of `void foo();` changes the meaning of `foo` in the typedef from referring to `struct foo` to the name of the function `foo`.