# Templated class hierarchy does not warn about duplicate member name

Tags: c++, clang

I have been refactoring, moving members from children classes to a common parent.

I'd like to use compiler warnings/errors to protect against the same variable appearing in child and parent (if I forgot to remove from a child).

The below produces a warning with Clang 16/17:

```
struct P
{
    int a;
};


struct C : public P
{
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

.

```
warning: non-static data member 'a' of 'C' shadows member inherited from type 'P' [-Wshadow-field]
```

However, in my situation I had a templated hierarchy:

```
template<class E>
struct P
{
    int a;
};

template<class E>
struct C : public P<E>
{
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    C<double> c;
    return 0;
}
```

and this does not produce a warning. Why is this?

Comment: The standard doesn't require to produce warnings. It's a compiler implementation detail. What if you specialize `struct P` for some type `E`, so `P<E>` doesn't have `int a;`? How can the compiler guess this case in `struct C : public P<E>`?

Comment: @273K I don't understand how any `P<E>` could not have `P<E>::a`?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/rYM5adP5G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of dependent names and template specialization.  When you do

```
template<class E>
struct C : public P<E>
{
    int a;
};
```

all you can really do is check that it is syntactically correct.  We don't know what `E` is yet so we can't know what `P<E>` will turn into.  There could be a specialization introduced after `C` that specializes `P` for `double` that has no members so there would be no member hiding.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is about name shadowing, not duplicate member names. When you have a dependent base class, no names are brought into the scope, so nothing can be shadowed.

In the non template case:

```cpp
struct P
{
    int a;
};


struct C : public P
{
    // `a` refers to the member of `P` here
    int a;
    // `a` now refers to the member of `C`, which shadows the member of `P`
};
```

In the templated case:

```cpp
template<class E>
struct C : public P<E>
{
    // Because `P<E>` is a dependent base class, `a` doesn't refer to anything here
    int a;
    // This declaration does not shadow anything
};
```

Clang simply does not have a warning for what you want to do currently.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai That's in a complete class context, which is after the class. e.g.: https://godbolt.org/z/jdxhWq1aY (This is still ill-formed, but that's unrelated to the warning: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15538759 )

Comment: oh wow, thanks for the explanation. Now I just dont understand why here `a` does refer to `C::a` https://compiler-explorer.com/z/GzEPnh8Yr. Initializer counst also as "complete class context"?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Yes it is: https://wg21.link/class.mem.general#7.5

Comment: I didnt dare to ask for the whole picture but you pointed me to exactly what I was  missing. Thanks a lot. I will delete comments.